# The best SQL Code to get this Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

Simply put,
  I have these tables.

```
Planning: 
  Date | Machine | Product | PlanningParts

OKParts: 
  Date | Machine | Product | OKParts

Scrap: 
  Date | Machine | Product | ScrapParts

Trials: 
  Date | Machine | Product | TrialParts

Breakdowns: 
  Date | Machine | Product | Minutes
```

These tables can have two or more records for a same [Date | Machine | Product], they are not unique columns.
 What is the best SQL Code(SQLite or SQL Server) to get this output?

```
Output:
  Date | Machine | Product | Planning | OKParts | ScrapParts | TrialParts | Minutes
```

Edit:
In the output, i need one line per [Date,Machine,Product] and the rest of the columns have to be the SUM
(I don't speak english, Sorry)

Eidted:
Example:
(I would not put the table "Trials" to make it shorter)

```
Planning:
     Date    | Machine | Product | PlanningParts
     1/6/12  |  Blower | A001    | 100
     2/6/12  |  Blower | A002    | 100
     2/6/12  | Assembly| B001    | 50

OKParts:
     Date   | Machine | Product  | OKParts
     1/6/12 | Blower  | A001     | 50
     1/6/12 | Blower  | A001     | 20
     1/6/12 | Blower  | A002     | 100

Scrap:
     Date   | Machine | Product  | ScrapParts | Reason
     1/6/12 | Blower  | A001     | 5          | Low Weight
     1/6/12 | Blower  | A001     | 3          | High Weight
     2/6/12 | Assembly| B001     | 4          | Bad Cut

Breakdowns
     Date   | Machine | Product  | Minutes    | Reason
     1/6/12 | Blower  | A001     | 100        | Manteinance
     1/6/12 | Blower  | A001     | 20         | Manteinance
     2/6/12 | Assembly| B001     | 100        | Quality approval


   OUTPUT:
         Date   | Machine | Product  | Planning | OKParts | ScrapParts | Breakdowns
         1/6/12 | Blower  | A001     | 100      | 70      | 8          | 120
         1/6/12 | Blower  | A002     | 100      | 100     | 0          | 0
         2/6/12 | Assembly| B001     | 50       | 0       | 4          | 100
```

Comment: Please show sample data (including a few rows where there are multiple values contributing to a single SUM) and desired results. This way, we don't have to ask 15 follow-up questions about the results, or guess about the query you need. If you show sample data and desired results, we can test and verify solutions *before* showing them to you and having you reject them because your requirements weren't clear.

Comment: If there is a record in one table, will the same {Date,Machine,Product} *always* have *at least* one record in all the other tables?  Or could they sometimes have 0 records for that {Date,Machine,Product}?  And/or is there one table that *always* has *at least* one record for that {Date,Machine,Product}?

Comment: Please read: http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - Excuse me, I had not read the first comment

Comment: @Dems - They sometimes have 0 records for that {Date,Machine,Product}

Comment: @leinho - From my earlier comment; `And/or is there one table that always has at least one record for that {Date,Machine,Product}?`

Comment: Would you please consider selecting an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a CTE unioning all the tables into one, then using the SUM aggrigate function, add up the columns for each Date, Machine, Product group. A bit like this (not tested):

```
WITH AllParts AS (
SELECT Date, Machine, Product, PlanningParts, NULL AS OKParts, NULL AS ScrapParts, NULL AS TrialParts, NULL AS Breakdowns
FROM Planning
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, Machine, Product,NULL AS PlanningParts, OKParts, NULL AS ScrapParts, NULL AS TrialParts, NULL AS Breakdowns
FROM OKParts
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, Machine, Product,NULL AS PlanningParts, NULL AS OKParts, ScrapParts, NULL AS TrialParts, NULL AS Breakdowns
FROM Scrap
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, Machine, Product,NULL AS PlanningParts, NULL AS OKParts, NULL AS ScrapParts, TrialParts, NULL AS Breakdowns
FROM Trials
UNION ALL
SELECT Date, Machine, Product,NULL AS PlanningParts, NULL AS OKParts, NULL AS ScrapParts, TrialParts, Breakdowns
FROM BreakDowns
)
SELECT
Date, Machine, Product, SUM(OKParts) AS OKParts, SUM(ScrapParts) AS ScrapParts, SUM(TrialParts) AS TrialParts, SUM(BreakDowns) AS Breakdowns
FROM AllParts
GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
```

Comment: Not the easiest to read, but certainly works.  And doesn't have the duplication causing problems of the JOIN version.

Comment: That's what I have already, but I see the code and it looks pretty dirty. There must be a more efficient way of doing

Comment: Obviously aliasing is not required for all the unions (only the top one) but I wrote it like this to make it clearer what was going on. Removing the unnecessary aliases would make it a bit easier to read! This is the most efficient way I could think of doing this seeing as `UNION ALL`s require very little work.

Comment: @leinho just because the code looks dirty, doesn't make it inefficient!

Comment: For me too, but was waiting for someone to show me a better way. You may not be. It is a very low point for SQL, not having a good method for these cases. Just thanks for the reply!

Comment: @jaypeagi - is very inefficient because you are putting a lot of columns with null values ​​that are unnecessary. That strikes a lot in performance

Comment: The only other way I can think of that may be more efficient would be to store the data in a table like the one produced by the CTE in the first place. Writing queries to get the data in the format its in currently from this "super table" would be cleaner.

Comment: @leinho come on now, don't blame the tool because your design is not optimal or because your query requirements are not geared to your design or vice versa.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - The model is simple, tell me another way to create the tables and make a better query.The most likely is that I'm wrong and SQL is prepared for this type of case or is there a better way to design the model. But not until I discover , or someone show me that

Comment: @leinho I've asked *multiple times* for you to post some sample data so I can understand what your model is actually storing, but you haven't bothered to do that... <shrug>

Comment: Sorry, thought I was clear in the example. Want to display columns with possible values?

Comment: @Leinho this is NOT as inefficient as you think. Those NULL values are really not going to affect performance much at ALL.

Comment: I did a test and I am not convinced

Comment: @leinho - Do all your tables have indexes on {Date,Machine,Product} as a single composite index?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested to see if SUMming after the UNION performs as well as this query that SUMs first:

```
WITH Vals AS (
   SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'PlanningParts' Which, Sum(PlanningParts) Value FROM Planning GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
   UNION ALL SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'OKParts', Sum(OKParts) FROM OKParts GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
   UNION ALL SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'ScrapParts', Sum(ScrapParts) FROM Scrap GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
   UNION ALL SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'TrialParts', Sum(TrialParts) FROM Trials GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
   UNION ALL SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'Minutes', Sum(Minutes) FROM Breakdowns GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
)
SELECT *
FROM Vals
PIVOT (Max(Value) FOR Which IN (PlanningParts, OKParts, ScrapParts, TrialParts, Minutes)) P;
```

Yeah, it's painful, but that's what you get from the given database design. Refactoring these 5 tables into one table, with views replacing these tables having instead-of triggers *could* be viable.

Note: PIVOT is for SQL Server 2005 and up. But you don't even need PIVOT:

```
WITH Vals AS (
   SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'PlanningParts' Which, Sum(PlanningParts) Value FROM Planning GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
   UNION ALL SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'OKParts', Sum(OKParts) FROM OKParts GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
   UNION ALL SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'ScrapParts', Sum(ScrapParts) FROM Scrap GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
   UNION ALL SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'TrialParts', Sum(TrialParts) FROM Trials GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
   UNION ALL SELECT Date, Machine, Product, 'Minutes', Sum(Minutes) FROM Breakdowns GROUP BY Date, Machine, Product
)
SELECT
   Date, Machine, Product,
   Sum(CASE Which WHEN 'PlanningParts' THEN Value END) PlanningParts,
   Sum(CASE Which WHEN 'OKParts' THEN Value END) OKParts,
   Sum(CASE Which WHEN 'ScrapParts' THEN Value END) ScrapParts,
   Sum(CASE Which WHEN 'TrialParts' THEN Value END) TrialParts,
   Sum(CASE Which WHEN 'Minutes' THEN Value END) Minutes
FROM Vals;
```

Switching the text `Which` values to integers will probably yield a speed improvement.

In regards to my comment/question about a table with a distinct list of the Date, Machine, Product values that are in your tables, this query would provide such a list. This won't perform well, but it should give you the idea.

```
WITH DistinctKeys AS ( --wishing we had this as a real table
   SELECT Date, Machine, Product FROM Planning
   UNION SELECT Date, Machine, Product FROM OKParts
   UNION SELECT Date, Machine, Product FROM Scrap
   UNION SELECT Date, Machine, Product FROM Trials
   UNION SELECT Date, Machine, Product FROM Breakdown
) -- because then we could do this:
SELECT
   K.Date, K.Machine, K.Part,
   (SELECT Sum(PlanningParts) FROM Planning X ON EXISTS (SELECT K.* INTERSECT SELECT X.Date, X.Machine, X.Product) PlanningParts
   (SELECT Sum(OKParts) FROM OKParts X ON EXISTS (SELECT K.* INTERSECT SELECT X.Date, X.Machine, X.Product) OKParts
   (SELECT Sum(ScrapParts) FROM Scrap X ON EXISTS (SELECT K.* INTERSECT SELECT X.Date, X.Machine, X.Product) Scrap
   (SELECT Sum(TrialParts) FROM Trials X ON EXISTS (SELECT K.* INTERSECT SELECT X.Date, X.Machine, X.Product) TrialParts
   (SELECT Sum(Minutes) FROM Breakdown X ON EXISTS (SELECT K.* INTERSECT SELECT X.Date, X.Machine, X.Product) Minutes
FROM
   DistinctKeys K;
```

But frankly, the JOINs are not going to perform as well as the UNIONs previously given in my and @jaypeagi's answers.

One more thing: do NOT assume what the performance is going to be of a query. Even experts check execution plans and collect real IO and CPU statistics to determine this information. Your worries about NULLs reducing performance are likely completely unfounded.

If you have good indexes on your tables on [Date, Machine, Product] then you will probably get reasonably good performance out of the UNION methods.

Comment: Better!, Did not know the keyword "PIVOT". But I still like watching dirty. You got any idea how to make the model better?. I commented that several of these tables have more columns. Example: Scrap and Breakdowns table has one column more, "Reason", so you can have:

Scrap:
  1/6/12 | Blower | Tank | 5 | Under Weight
  1/6/12 | Blower | Tank | 3 | Weight High

Comment: If you are using the supertype/subtype pattern where your tables have different columns even though they basically represent the same kinds of things, then perhaps your database structure is okay. If the number of columns is not really *that* much different, then putting everything in the same table may still be best, just leaving columns NULL when they don't apply to the type of item.

Comment: @leinho Do you have a table with a distinct list of the Date, Machine, and Product values that will be found in these 5 tables?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the question. There is not unique columns. And in the five tables the values of Date can be any date, Machine and Product are the same JOINs in the five tables to Machines.ID AND Products.ID (Other two tables) . Sorry about my english

Comment: @leinho - We want to know how to get a list of the {Date,Machine,Prodcut}s that exist in your data.  You say that each table could have 0 records for a {Date,Machine,Product} that exists in another table.  It's *normal* practice in such cases to have a *Dimension Table* that has exactly ***one*** record for each {Date,Machine,Product}.  This can make queries and constraints much easier to implement.

Comment: @Erike!! You're right, what I said about nulls is wrong. I had tried it but it seems that something happened to me because I did it and gave me an acceptable performance. Thanks!